# how get the center coordinate (x,y) of the imageview which is (0,0 ) by touch

Tags: android

When I touch the center of imageview I would like to get the center coordinate (x,y) of the image which is (0,0) in android. Please help me with that.

This is my code to get the coordinate :

this is my code to get the coordinate

```
imageAnim.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"x ="+  event.getX()+" y ="+  event.getY(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
            return false;
        }
    });
```

layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background = "#000000"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="100sp" />

<ZoomControls
    android:id="@+id/zoomControls1"
    android:layout_width="211dp"
    android:layout_height="311dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="156dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="211dp"
    android:layout_height="211dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="165dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:src="@android:drawable/menuitem_background" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSecondPage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zoomControls1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/zoomControls1"
    android:src="@drawable/images" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="87dp"
    android:text="next page " />
```

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView v;
MotionEvent event;
 ZoomControls zoom;
  ImageView imageAnim;
   Button k;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  final ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
      k=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

  final Intent n=new Intent (MainActivity.this,second.class);

  k.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(n);   
    }
    });

   AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon), 300);
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.images), 300);
   animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sss), 300);
   animation.setOneShot(false);
   imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
   animation.start();

       imageAnim.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        int offsetX = imageAnim.getWidth()/2 , offsetY = imageAnim.getHeight()/2;


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()," the off x ="+ offsetX +" the y =      "+offsetY,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()," the x ="+  (event.getX()-offsetX) +
                " the y ="+(event.getY()-offsetY) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
            return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think you want to get the center co ordinates of the image View...

Comment: yes  which is (0,0) and when i touch the left side it is will (-x,y) or (-x,-y) it is like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a view, `event.getX()` , `event.getY()` returns the relative coordinates, if you want the absolute coordinates on screen use `event.getRawX()` , `event.getRawY()`

**EDIT**

If for some reason you need your center to be (0,0) you need to make your own offset,

```
imageAnim.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        int offsetX = getWidth()/2 , offsetY = getheight()/2;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"x ="+  (event.getX()-offsetX) +
                " y ="+(event.getY()-offsetY) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: what i want is the coordinates of the image it self but when i press in center of the image it does not return (0,0) even when i use event.getRawY() and event.getRawX()

Comment: (0,0) is the top left corner, center is (getwidth()/2,getHeight/2)

Comment: when i touch in the first pic in my first activity at top left corner it give me (0,0) , but the second pic in second activity  it does not give me (0,0) it is give me (0.35 , 41) or (0.44 ,44) or (0.3,43) the y are not close at all to 0 is this normal ?

Comment: int offsetX = imageAnim.getWidth()/2 , offsetY = imageAnim.getHeight()/2; the offsetX and offsety it is return 0